# possible for an iPhone app to make the iPhone "go dark" for a specified number of minutes?

Tags: iphone

Can an iPhone app be made to stop all calls and text messages for a specified number of minutes, that is, prevent the user from making or getting calls and messages? Can an app turn the device off temporarily? Context: help kids to concentrate while doing their homework/studying and not be interrupted with calls and text-messages from their schoolmates.

Comment: http://blogs.forbes.com/andygreenberg/2010/08/11/apple-patches-jailbreakme-will-iphone-jailbirds-sacrifice-liberty-for-security/  Try an Android phone instead.

Comment: If you are planning to release your app,this is not a thought at all,Apple will rip you off.!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not if you want to get into the App Store or run on non-jailbroken devices, no. One of the guiding principles of the SDK is that you can't "break" core functionality like inbound phone calls or SMSs. You will get notified that your app is about to enter a background state (or terminate), but you can't stop the user taking the call or terminating your app.

For information in events that you do get, have a look at [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate).